# Getting alert dialog properties

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to check if dialog is showing and if it is then save its title, message, button titles in `onSaveInstanceState()` method and display an alert with saved properties next time activity is restored from saved bundle.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to switch to a dialog fragment http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html. That fragment can retain its instance automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have your custom dialog,which will store the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use alert.isShowing() [alert is object of AlertDialog] to know alertdialog is showing or not. And then you can save data into onSaveInstanceState() method.